# How to include behavior within reusable element in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, custom-element

I am trying to make a reusable element in Polymer 1.0.

I am running into an issue with canonical paths when trying to load a behavior from within a custom element package.

The behavior is at the same level in my file structure as my custom element.

My current import appears as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="extras-behavior.html">
```

However, I receive this warning:

> Behavior ExtrasBehavior not found when mixing properties into
>   mcd-price-calories!

I believe this is due to polyserve and how it converts imports into canonical paths.

Is it possible to do this currently without making the behavior its own bower package?

Comment: can you share your element code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this actually was not a syntax issue but merely a warning given by Polymer. In order to make sure this warning is not given you must place a comment about your behavior declaration like so:

```
<script>
  /** @polymerBehavior ConfigBehavior */
  ConfigBehavior = {
  };
</script>
```

Now Polymer's engine will "know" about your behavior and cease to throw this warning.